# How to get multiple resultset in knex?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I am using SQL server and I have one procedure which returning two result set.
Following is the result set.

```
{
   records : [
                {name : "abc", age: 26},
                {name : "def", age: 22},
                {name : "ghi", age: 29}
            ],
   totalCount : 10
}
```

I am using Knex in node.js for Databese Operation. I am able to get **records** (which is first result set of my SP result) but can not able to get **totalCount**.

below is my code for executing stored procedure.

```
const getUserList= async ({arg1, arg2, knexInstance}) => { 
    const results = await knexInstance.raw(
        `exec dbo.getUsers @arg1=?, @arg1=?, [
            arg1, arg2
        ]
    );
```

I already go through with [this](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/2222) but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get multiple result sets in knex. As explained in the knex issue that you linked, you have to use mssql or tedious driver directly to be able to do it.